# how to convert hijri date to gregorian date using php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

please help me

how to convert hijri date to Gregorian date using php

if you know any date picker which can convert hijri to Gregorian, please let me know.

Comment: Have a quick google for `php date hijri` and you'll find loads of people doing this.

Comment: i think this might help: http://keith-wood.name/calendars.html

Answer (score 4):

check this [solution](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.calendar.php#54234). quoting here

```
<?php

class HijriCalendar
{
    function monthName($i) // $i = 1..12
    {
        static $month  = array(
            "Muḥarram", "Safar", "Rabī‘ I", "Rabī‘ II",
            "Jumādá I", "Jumādá II", "Rajab", "Sha‘bān",
            "Ramaḍān", "Shawwāl", "Dhū al-Qa‘dah", "Dhū al-Ḥijjah"
        );
        return $month[$i-1];
    }

    function GregorianToHijri($time = null)
    {
        if ($time === null) $time = time();
        $m = date('m', $time);
        $d = date('d', $time);
        $y = date('Y', $time);

        return HijriCalendar::JDToHijri(
            cal_to_jd(CAL_GREGORIAN, $m, $d, $y));
    }

    function HijriToGregorian($m, $d, $y)
    {
        return jd_to_cal(CAL_GREGORIAN,
            HijriCalendar::HijriToJD($m, $d, $y));
    }

    # Julian Day Count To Hijri
    function JDToHijri($jd)
    {
        $jd = $jd - 1948440 + 10632;
        $n  = (int)(($jd - 1) / 10631);
        $jd = $jd - 10631 * $n + 354;
        $j  = ((int)((10985 - $jd) / 5316)) *
            ((int)(50 * $jd / 17719)) +
            ((int)($jd / 5670)) *
            ((int)(43 * $jd / 15238));
        $jd = $jd - ((int)((30 - $j) / 15)) *
            ((int)((17719 * $j) / 50)) -
            ((int)($j / 16)) *
            ((int)((15238 * $j) / 43)) + 29;
        $m  = (int)(24 * $jd / 709);
        $d  = $jd - (int)(709 * $m / 24);
        $y  = 30*$n + $j - 30;

        return array($m, $d, $y);
    }

    # Hijri To Julian Day Count
    function HijriToJD($m, $d, $y)
    {
        return (int)((11 * $y + 3) / 30) +
            354 * $y + 30 * $m -
            (int)(($m - 1) / 2) + $d + 1948440 - 385;
    }
};

$hijri = HijriCalendar::GregorianToHijri( time() );
echo $hijri[1].'. '.HijriCalendar::monthName($hijri[0]).' '.$hijri[2];

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use HijriDateLib at
http://github.com/hubaishan/HijriDatelib
It is very useful and used in many project like WordPress WP-Hijri plugin

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use the [Dcter](https://github.com/hanifhefaz/dcter) package for this purpose. This package is designed to convert Hijri date to Gregorian and Gregorian to Jalali and vice versa.

It currently consists of 6 methods to convert dates, namely, HijriToGregorian, GregorianToHijri, JulianToHijri, HijriToJulian, GregorianToJalali and JalaliToGregorian methods.

Since the package converts dates to `YYYY-MM-DD` format, you can use the its `Carbonize` method to make a carbon date object from the converted date.