# Javascript function result in CI controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a javascript function suppose function will be

```
function GregorianToHijri(dt)
{
    var calendar = $.calendars.instance('gregorian');
    var date = calendar.parseDate('mm/dd/yyyy',dt);
    calendar = $.calendars.instance('ummalqura');
    date = calendar.fromJD(date.toJD());
    return calendar.formatDate('mm/dd/yyyy', date);
}
```

I need to get the result of this function in codeigniter controller. ie i need to pass the parameter from controller and want to get the result in controller. is there any way to do this?

Comment: Give your flow and expected output

Comment: Simply, In my controller i have a date, i want to convert that date to Hijri date. so there is a javascript function to convert Gregorian date to Hijri date. I want to get the Hijiri date in my controller. I dont know how to get it this

Comment: Why dont you use php for this: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30865498/how-to-convert-hijri-date-to-gregorian-date-using-php?rq=1

Comment: there is 1 day difference when using these php functions